# Convert a char array to an int to stop program

Tags: c, arrays

I'm creating an edit distance program that takes in two string pointers and returns the edit distance between them. The only issue I'm having is ending the program. Basically when the user enters -1 for both strings, the program should end. I've been trying all types of things and searches but can't seem to get it to stop.
This is what I have:

```
char * word1;
char * word2;
char string1[1000];
char string2[1000];
int d;


do{
printf("Enter first string:");
scanf("%s", &string1);
printf("Enter second string:");
scanf("%s", &string2);
if((int)string1[0] == -1 && (int)string2[0] == -1)
        break;
printf("%d\n", string1[0]);
word1 = string1;
word2 = string2;

printf("%s\n", word1);
printf("%s\n", word2);
d = distance (word1, word2);
printf ("The edit distance between %s and %s is %d.\n",word1, word2, d);
}while((int)string1[0] != -1);

return 0;
```

Comment: Instead of "f((int)string1[0] == -1 && (int)string2[0] == -1) break;", try "if (antoi(string1) == -1 && antoi(string2) == -1) break;".  If the user enters "-1" for the first string, and then "-1" for the second string, it will break out.  Your tests of string1[0] and string2[0] are actually looking at the minus sign ('-') - if the user enters "-1" and "-1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checking `(int)string1[0] == -1` is not good enough. This condition checks if the first char of string1 is '-1'. Of course this is not true as you enter two chars '-' and '1' (and the terminating `\0`).

You can check it correctly in two ways. As stings:

```
!strcmp(string1, "-1")
```

As integers:

```
atoi(string1) == -1
```

Answer (score 3):

The line "printf("%d\n", string1[0]);" doesn't make sense.  You're treating the first character of the string that was parsed as a number.  It's a character.  Oh, it will print a number, but not what you expect.  What you really want to do is parse the whole string to an integer.  Use atoi(string1) to get that.

Also, instead of

```
if ((int)string1[0] == -1 && (int)string2[0] == -1)
    break;"
```

Do this:

```
if (atoi(string1) == -1 && atoi(string2) == -1)
    break;
```

That way, if the user enters "-1" for the first string, and "-1" for the second string, it will break out.

Remember - you are dealing with strings, not single characters.

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The question is already well answered in terms of the misunderstanding between stings and integers.  In C strings and arrays are not *first-class data types*, and you cannot convert a string to an integer simply by casting it.  However you might consider whether the method you have chosen to terminate the program actually makes any sense; thinking laterally, it would make more sense, be simpler to program and more intuitive for the user to simply enter *empty* strings to end input:

```
if( string1[0] == '\0' && string2[0] == '\0' )
        break;
```

or more simply still, just:

```
if( string1[0] == string2[0] == '\0' )
        break;
```